# Magento Blocks Permission in Admin Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, cms-block, cms-pages

I saw this option in store admin of Magento 1.9 by going to System - > Permission -> blocks. The questions are:
- How do I use it?
- I have a third party extension where is displays recently added blogs. I want to move this block to the CMS home page. Will adding the block here allow me to call it from CMS block?
- When adding a new block to this list, how do I know the name of the block?

Note that I am mainly interested in moving some blocks of third party extension to different custom CMS pages. 
Another example, I have an extension (ramification extension) wherein some page it displays top users who have purchased most from the store. It currently displays it on some page of the extension and wants to display the same on the home page. How do I know the block name, and make use of store admin to be able to call it in static blocks or CMS page?

Answer (score 1):

In that permission section, you need to enter block type. The custom block type can be found from frontend layout file.